# How to append byte data in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, hex, byte, arrays

How to append the eight values of a byte array `uint8_t[8]` into one variable `uint64_t`?

```
 uint8_t array[8] = { 0xe4, 0x52, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0xa4, 0x63, 0x95, 0x8f };

 uint64_t result = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); ++i)
 {
     // what to do here?
 }
```

In the example above, `result` should end up with the value `0xe452cbbea463958f`. I am looking for a general solution that is not bound to exactly eight elements from the array.

Comment: `result <<= 8; result |= array[i];`

Comment: @H2CO3: Yeah, that would do it.  Can one just be cast to the other?

Comment: @RobertHarvey As far as I can tell, no (strict aliasing). `memcpy()` could be used, though, if the machine was big-endian (which is unlikely nowadays).

Comment: Hmm.  Casting these two would be trivial in C#.  Both would be little endian anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 `result = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(array)` won't do the trick? Still big-endian of course.

Comment: @H2CO3 If this works, could you please write an answer? I do understand the first operation, but not the second one. Moreover, I don't have the intuition why shifting left wouldn't reverse the order the array elements are appended.

Comment: @Inspired That sounds pretty straight forward. Does it work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fortunately, C++ is not C# :P

Comment: @H2CO3: Damn right. :)

Comment: @Inspired Still, strict aliasing. Not sure if that works (I'm searching for a relevant SO question/answer).

Comment: @danijar The `|=` operator is a bitwise OR-assignment. After shifting the previous byte to the left by 8 places, it inserts the new byte to the end of the 64-bit integer. (if you try to work it out on paper, it's definitely easier to grok.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey :) Of course, this is the case when higher-level languages beat lower-level ones.

Comment: @danijar Just checked with GCC, it works, but of course it inverts the order of bytes on my little-endian machine.

Comment: @H2CO3 Okay, that makes sense to me. I didn't know of the `|=` operator before. You could write an answer and I'll mark is as accepted.

Comment: @Inspired Nice that you tested it. Would that even work when the array is longer but I still only want to append the first eight values?

Comment: @H2CO3: Strict aliasing works if it's an `unsigned char` array.

Comment: @danijar Yes, it would. It just takes 8 bytes from the beginning of the array and puts it into `result`.

Comment: @Inspired Great to know!

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, I almost always forget that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to copy the bytes in order, the best way is to use memcpy:

```
memcpy(&result, array, sizeof(array));
```

But if you want to interpret the bytes as being part of a larger number, and treat them as if they were in big-endian order, you have to use the loop that H2CO3 provided:

```
result = 0;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array); i++) {
    result <<= 8;
    result |= array[i];
}
```

If you want to be able to use the same variable as either a byte array of a 64-bit integer, you could simply typecast.  Or if you're writing in C you could use a union.

```
union myBigInt {
    uint8_t asBytes[8];
    uint64_t asLongInt;
};
```

Comment: Reading from an inactive member of a union is undefined behavior.  The other information is good though.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's again something that works in C, but not in C++. :)

Comment: Ha, my C++ must be rusty.  Too much Javascript and Python.  Corrected my answer.

Comment: @slashingweapon indeed! Such very high-level languages are perfect for 1. learning (while a beginner wants to focus on algorithms that "just work" instead of having to deal with memory and stuff), 2. scripting, but they are definitively bad for teaching bare-metal programming.

Answer (score 3):

This is how:

```
result <<= 8;
result |= array[i];
```

The `|=` operator means "assignment after bitwise OR". After `result` is shifted to the left by 8 places (what `<<=` does), the new byte is inserted to its end.